# Splitting existing gradle dependency into multiple modules

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-library, aar

I currently have published library on maven central. The library is android library `.aar` project.
The problem is that current library needs to be split into multiple libraries while maintaining currently published library artifactId for backward compatibility. Here is an example what i have and what i'm trying to achieve.

Current artifactId

```
compile 'com.example:my-library:1.0.0'
```

New artifactId

```
compile 'com.example:my-library-core:1.0.0'
compile 'com.example:my-library-deps-1:1.0.0'
compile 'com.example:my-library-deps-2:1.0.0'

compile 'com.example:my-library:1.0.0' (with deps)
--> compile 'com.example:my-library-core:1.0.0'
--> compile 'com.example:my-library-deps-1:1.0.0'
--> compile 'com.example:my-library-deps-2:1.0.0'
```

So basically the idea is to keep the original `com.example:my-library` maven artifactId which will only have dependencies to 3 newly created libraries to support backward compatibility for old customers.

Now i've tried locally to have a `pom` file without artifact and with dependencies only, but gradle doesn't pull artifacts from dependencies from some reason.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question.

The solution is to have a separate module that will have no classes and empty manifest, resulting in empty `.aar` archive. This will allow you to keep the existing artifact ID with dependencies to new modules.